# arrange variable sized images in listbox in windows phone

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, listbox, wrappanel

i have used wrappanel to arrange images within a listbox but in my picture collection some images have different sizes. Some are horizontal and some are vertical. Due to different orientation, there is some spaces between the images which is not so good in vision. Can any body suggest me any way to remove these spaces?

thanks

[image]

i am using following code but still the problem is same...

```
<ListBox Name="lstBoxMyRecentPhotos"
                                         MaxHeight="650"
                                         Margin="0,8,0,0"
                                         SelectionChanged="lstImageList_SelectionChanged">
                                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <toolkit1:VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemHeight="200" ItemWidth="230" />
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>

                                            <Border Name="brdr"
                                                    Margin="5"
                                                    BorderBrush="White"
                                                    BorderThickness="3">
                                                <Border.Background>
                                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/capsule_image_holder.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
                                                </Border.Background>
                                                <Image Width="{Binding width}"
                                                       Height="{Binding height}"
                                                       Hold="imgRecent_Hold"
                                                       Source="{Binding photoUrl}"
                                                       Stretch="UniformToFill">

                                                </Image>
                                            </Border>

                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                                </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways

1. Make the image always stretch UniformToFill and use hardcoded size - that way it will uniformly fill the space that it's been given and all the photos will use the given space nicely
2. Use [VariableSizedWrapGrid](https://github.com/Kinnara/WPToolkit).

> Provides a grid-style layout panel where each tile/cell can be
>   variable size based on content. Similar to the WinRT
>   VariableSizedWrapGrid.

Comment: i tried with VariableSizedWrapGrid but in VariableSizedWrapGrid we have to predefine height and width so i am getting same size image

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which toolkit you are using for the VariableSizedWrapGrid, but are you sure that you need to set its ItemHeight? What happens if you don't?

I'm personally using Telerik's controls to give me a WrapGrid. If you have access to their controls, I can share an example.

Here's what my implementation looks like:

[image]

Comment: when i do not provide the ItemHeight it fires and unhandled exception.. we have to buy the subscription for Telerik's control and being a new developer, i think i cannot afford for this... so can you provide me any alternatives. Any sample would be more helpful.